# Ajaxify RadGrid and label from code behind

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I am trying to Ajaxify RadGrid control and label in code behind. Here is my code. But the Label value doesn't get refresh when the RadGrid changed. Could you please let me know what could be wrong here?

Thank you for any help.

```
                    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server"> 
                        <AjaxSettings> 
                            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1"> 
                                <UpdatedControls> 
                                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" /> 
                                </UpdatedControls> 
                            </telerik:AjaxSetting> 
                        </AjaxSettings> 
                    </telerik:RadAjaxManager> 

                    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"> 
                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"> 
                            <MasterTableView> 
                                <Columns> 
                                </Columns> 
                            </MasterTableView> 
                        </telerik:RadGrid> 
                    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel> 
        <div id="div1" runat="server"> 
            <table id="table1" runat="server" > 
                <tr> 
                    <td align="center"> 
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"> </asp:Label> 
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
            </table> 
        </div>
```

Code behind.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
            { 
               RadAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(RadGrid1, lblName, null); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code snippet or demo.
This worked correctly on my side.
let me know if any issue.

.aspx

```
 <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
    AllowPaging="True" OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" />
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();

    dynamic data = new[] {
            new { ID = 1, Name ="Name1", customdate=dt,NO = 11.00},
            new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2", customdate=dt,NO = 11.00},
            new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3", customdate=dt,NO = 11.00},
            new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4", customdate=dt.AddYears(2011),NO = 11.44},
            new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5", customdate=dt,NO = 10.4}
        };

    RadGrid1.DataSource = data;
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(RadGrid1, Label1, null);
}
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

by above example if you change the pagesize of radgrid then it will also update the label text.

Answer (score 0):

Try without using the overload for the loading panel:

```
RadAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(RadGrid1, lblName);
```

If that still doesn't work, try something like this:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(RadGrid1);
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lblName);
```

Comment: I tried without using the overload. I still have the same issue. Also tried the second code block but I got 'must implement INamingContainer or IPostBackEventHandler' error for 'lblName' control.